# How to programmatically create Ant Builder in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I develop Eclipse plugin which should programmatically create Ant Builder for specified project.

The same way as using UI: Properties->Builders->New->Ant Builder.

I tried to find solution several weeks but without success. 
Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Following might not  be the cleanest way of doing what you are asking, but works. This adds a builder called "MyBuilderName" to the project's builders. You then need to create a file called "MyBuilderName.launch" under the folder .externalToolBuilders under the project folder.

Make an Ant builder and check the file in .externalToolBuilders folder to see what it should look like.

```
...
IProjectDescription desc = project.getDescription();
ICommand[] commands = desc.getBuildSpec();
ICommand[] newcommands = new ICommand[commands.length + 1];
System.arraycopy(commands, 0, newcommands, 1, commands.length);

ICommand command = desc.newCommand();
command.setBuilderName(
    "org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ExternalToolBuilder");            
command.setArguments(
    Collections.singletonMap("LaunchConfigHandle", 
    "<project>/.externalToolBuilders/MyBuilderName"));
newcommands[0] = command;
desc.setBuildSpec(newcommands);
project.setDescription(desc, monitor);
...
```